# CardinalityViolation when trying to use nested subqueries to retrieve JSON from Postgres using SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to translate the following Postgres query into Sqlalchemy 1.4:

```
SELECT json_build_object(
               'type', 'FeatureCollection',
               'features', json_agg(
                       json_build_object(
                           'type', 'Feature',
                           'geometry', geom,
                           'properties', (
                                select json_build_object(
                                    'id', hi.id,
                                    'responses', (
                                        select json_object_agg(e.etype, er.response)
                                        from expert e
                                            inner join expertresponse er on e.id = er.expert_id
                                        where infra_id = hi.id
                                    ),
                                    'protections', (
                                    select json_object_agg(p.ptype, i.pscore)
                                    from protection p
                                        inner join infraprotection i on p.id = i.protection_id
                                    where infra_id = hi.id
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                   )
           ) as allinfra
from hardinfra hi;
```

So I define the subqueries in the same order:

```
responses = (
    db.session.query(
        (func.json_object_agg(Expert.etype, Expert_Response.response)).label(
            "responses"
        )
    )
    .join(Expert_Response.exp)
    .filter(Expert_Response.infra_id == Hardinfra.id)
    .scalar_subquery()
)

protections = (
    db.session.query(
        (func.json_object_agg(Protection.ptype, Infra_Protection.pscore)).label(
            "protections"
        )
    )
    .join(Infra_Protection.prot)
    .filter(Infra_Protection.infra_id == Hardinfra.id)
    .scalar_subquery()
)

properties = db.session.query(
    (
        func.json_build_object(
            "id", Hardinfra.id, "protections", protections, "responses", responses
        ).label("properties")
    )
).scalar_subquery()

features = db.session.query(
    (
        func.json_build_object(
            "type",
            "Feature",
            "geometry",
            Hardinfra.geom,
            "properties",
            properties,
        ).label("features")
    )
).scalar_subquery()

q = db.session.query(
    func.json_build_object(
        "type", "FeatureCollection", "features", func.json_agg(features)
    )
)
```

However I get a `(psycopg2.errors.CardinalityViolation) more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` error when `features` is evaluated. I'm not even sure that `properties` and `features` need to be scalar subqueries (`responses` and `protections` certainly do), but I'm clearly also doing something else wrong, perhaps to do with correlating the inner `Hardinfra` refs to the outer ref? I'm not sure…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be caused by redundant subqueries, you could try to remove the last two subqueries.

```py
responses = (
    db.session.query(
        (func.json_object_agg(Expert.etype, Expert_Response.response)).label(
            "responses"
        )
    )
    .join(Expert_Response.exp)
    .filter(Expert_Response.infra_id == Hardinfra.id)
    .scalar_subquery()
)

protections = (
    db.session.query(
        (func.json_object_agg(Protection.ptype, Infra_Protection.pscore)).label(
            "protections"
        )
    )
    .join(Infra_Protection.prot)
    .filter(Infra_Protection.infra_id == Hardinfra.id)
    .scalar_subquery()
)

properties = func.json_build_object(
            "id", Hardinfra.id, "protections", protections, "responses", responses
        )

features = func.json_build_object(
            "type",
            "Feature",
            "geometry",
            Hardinfra.geom,
            "properties",
            properties,
        )

q = db.session.query(
    func.json_build_object(
        "type", "FeatureCollection", "features", func.json_agg(features)
    )
)
```